# Is there any way I can implement pagination using a DataView?

Tags: c#, datatable, pagination, dataview, pagedlist

I have a large database and anytime I try to load it to the DataGridView, the UI hangs.
I tried to use a BackGroundWorker for the job but that was no use. I therefore decided to use pagination (Thanks to a tutorial from FoxLearn).

My problem is that I have been unable to implement pagination using a DataView. I tried implementing it on my DataTable and I still faced the same problem.

Below is my attempted code:

```
    int pageNumber = 1;
            IPagedList<DataView> list;
    DataView transactionView = analyticsDataTable.DefaultView;
    
            private async void startPagination()
            {
                list = await GetPagedListAsync();
                backBtn.Enabled = list.HasPreviousPage;
                forwardBtn.Enabled = list.HasNextPage;
                AccountDGV.DataSource = list.ToList();
                pageLbl.Text = String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", pageNumber, list.PageCount);
    
            }
    
            public async Task<IPagedList<DataView>> GetPagedListAsync(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
            {
    
                return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    return transactionView.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);  
                });
            }
```

The error to the above code is:

> 'DataView' does not contain a definition for 'ToPagedList' and no
> accessible extension method 'ToPagedList' accepting a first argument
> of type 'DataView' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why was a Backgroundworker no use? You are using a different approach to threading here with the task factory.

Comment: Also, you are creating an IPagedList of dataview, implying that you expect the function to return a collection of data views. It's the other way round, you need a list of your datatype, then you pass that to your dataview as its datasource. But also, as you say, dataview does not contain a ToPagedList method. It's because you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I am relatively new to programming and a total newbie to threading. Perhaps, that is why I couldn't implement the pagination via BackGroundWorker. I have however been able to solve the problem. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved the problem

```
public async Task<IPagedList<DataRowView>> GetPagedListAsync(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 6)
{
   return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
        //Create a list of the rows in the DataView
        List<DataRowView> li = (from DataRowView row in transactionView select row).ToList();

        //Return a collection of the created list
        return li.AsEnumerable().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
   });
}
```